# The Riemann-Stieltjes integral is equal to a convergent serie

Tags: integration, analysis

This is a proof/exercise I found here in MSE but I don't see some steps of the proof.

The unit step function $I$ is defined by
$$
I(x)=
\begin{cases}0,\quad x \le 0, \\
1,\quad x>0.
\end{cases}
$$

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and suppose $c_n\geq 0$ for $n=1, 2, 3,\ldots$ and $\sum_n c_n$ is convergent. Let $\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_n I(x-s_n)$ where ${s_n}$ is a sequence of distinct points in $(a,b)$. Then 
$$
\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^{N}c_n f(s_n).
$$

Proof:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
 \int_{a}^{b}f(x)d\alpha(x)&=&\int_{a}^{b}f(x)d\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_n I(x-s_n)\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)d\left( I(x-s_n)\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\frac{d\left( I(x-s_n)\right)}{dx}dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\delta(x-s_n)dx\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^{N}c_n f(s_n)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

My doubts are in the last two equalities: Why $\frac{d(I(x-s_n))}{dx}=\delta (x-s_n)?$ and why $\int_a^bf(x)\delta (x-s_n)dx=f(s_n)?$

Note: I asked the owner of the proof about it but he didn't answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac Delta, a generalised function *defined* such that $\forall x\in \Bbb R: (x\neq 0\to \delta(x)=0)$ and that $\int_\Bbb R \delta(x)\,\mathrm d x=1$.

Then $~\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^x\delta(t)\mathrm d t=0~$ and $~\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^x \delta(t)\mathrm d t~{=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t)\mathrm d t-\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}\int_x^\infty \delta(t)\mathrm d t \\=1-0}$

So $$\int_{0}^{x-s}\delta(t)\mathrm d t =\begin{cases}1 &:& x\geq s\\0 &:& x<s\end{cases} \\ = \mathbb{I}(x-s)$$

Similarly we can show that for any $a\leq s< b$ then $\int_a^b f(t)\delta(t-s)\mathrm d t = f(s)$

Comment: the arrows above the lim, why are in that form?

Comment: $\lim_{x\uparrow 0} f(x)~,~ \lim_{0>x\to 0} f(x)~,~\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)$ and similar notation mean: the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from below.

Comment: hmm isn't there a contradiction then? Here with $~\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^x\delta(t)\mathrm d t=0~$ and $~\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}\int_{-\infty}^x \delta(t)\mathrm d t~=1$ ? i.e. 0=1 ?

Comment: It's called a step discontinuity.